# Can't login to web chat on Android w/SE installed

Tags: bug, chat, android-app, mobile-web

I got a notification from the SE app, telling me about a mention from the chat. There's no support for chat in the app yet, so it opened the browser. That worked fine, except I couldn't log in, because every time I tried to, SE twigged it was a `*.stackoverflow.com/*` type link and opened the app. It's impossible to get to the login screen and so I can't interact with the chat.

Since the devs are aware chat is not supported on the app, would it be possible to blacklist chat domains so that the app doesn't block the login page until such a time as the app has a proper chat section?

Or is there some solution that I've missed?

Comment: *twigged it* makes me giggle.

Comment: Sorry about this, it's as you said, the app reacting to `*.stackoverflow.com`, we have a couple other wildcards (e.g. `*.stackexchange.com` for all the SE subdomain sites) which are harder to fix this for, but I can fix this for stackoverflow itself since the accepted subdomains are so few.

Comment: fwiw the app is supposed to recognize that it accidentally responded to that URI it doesn't support and spit you back into your default browser, I need to look into why that didn't happen.

Comment: I can do some tests if that would help